# Hiding keyboard prior to initiating ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, progressdialog

I have a keyboard that I absolutely need to have disappear before initiating my next functions. What I've determined is that the ProgressDialog is getting in the way. I took out the line and it works fine. Why can't the ProgressDialog show ***if and only if*** the keyboard has been put away? It seems to just have a mind of its own.

```
public void hideKeyboard(){
    View view = this.getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)((this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)));
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    ShowProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.saving_design));
    new SaveTemplateTask().execute();
}
```

**Update:** This seems to be the logic, but it still doesn't work. The ProgressDialog simply doesn't wait for the hideKeyboard to be verified as true or not.

I made hideKeyboard return a boolean.

```
public boolean hideKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ((this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)));
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then in a separate function:

```
    if (hideKeyboard()) {
        ShowProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.saving_design));
        new SaveTemplateTask().execute();
    }
```

Comment: Not everything is updated immediately in Android. Some UI components put off work using View.post(). In situations like yours I try to also use View.post to postpone execution of my updates until after system updates  are done. In your case, I would do it with ShowProgressDialog.

Comment: make your hide keyboard method return boolean value. Then check if that value is true then show your progress dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and used Toasts instead (one in my onCreate and on in the onPostExecute method of my new SaveTemplateTask... because the ProgressDialog tends to initiate **before** the keyboard is hidden (which is not what we want). This honestly just looked better anyway so I'm okay with the cop out, but would be interesting to know why the process described in my initial question above doesn't seem to run so smoothly.

```
hideKeyboard();

if (hideKeyboard()) {
     ShowProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.saving_design));
     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Saving design", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     new SaveTemplateTask().execute();
}
```

The second function:

```
public boolean hideKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ((this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)));
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context ctx) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // check if no view has focus:
        View v = ((Activity) ctx).getCurrentFocus();
        if (v == null)
            return;

        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Same as above. There is relationship between the ProgressDialog and the keyboard that needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple for hiding the key board.Use the below code as per your requirement

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: The question relates to hiding the keyboard prior to initializing the ProgressDialog so this answer isn't satisfactory unfortunately.

Comment: hi,you need to hide the keybord right.the code will works for hiding the keyboard.it need to used based on your requirement

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the problem. The keyboard needs to hide **before** the ProgressDialog is initiated. It's a timing problem I suppose.

Comment: when your progress bar will be invoked in onCreate().or any onclick

Comment: It's after a button click.

Comment: after button click ,and before progressbar create method and use the above code once.

Comment: I'm just saying it doesn't work because the ProgressDialog doesn't wait for the keyboard to disappear. The solution would have to be something similar to what Rediska said above.